# How I can position text near fontawesome icon?

Tags: html, position, font-awesome

I have list of tweets with font awesome ico. How I can position text near the icon like on the screenshot?

Screenshot:
[image]

If I use html below, I have text under the icon.

```
<ul class="tweets-list text-left">
                        <li>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>Check Out Dtbaker's @Arduino Sales Notification #System
                                    http://t.co/ WBFKIWHJ</p>
                                <span>3 days ago</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: why dont you use a table with each row as tr and the image as one td and text as another td. So they will align correctly

Comment: What about display: inline/inline-block or float?

Comment: I'm using flexbox. `display: inline-block` for `.icon` and `.text` classes?

Answer (score 0):

Belial this is simplest way to do your requirement, so ur icon will align exact horizontally with your text, here you can remove the ul and li if not required.  Let me know if dont want to use table, i will find another solution.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <ul class="tweets-list text-left">
    <li>
      <td>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Check Out Dtbaker's @Arduino Sales Notification #System
            http://t.co/ WBFKIWHJ</p>
          <span>3 days ago</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </li>
  </ul>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT 12/31**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="icon">
        <img width="50" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/socialmedia/512/Twitter-icon.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Check Out Dtbaker's @Arduino Sales Notification #System
          http://t.co/ WBFKIWHJ</p>
        <span>3 days ago</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle :: https://jsfiddle.net/ufy6t9kd/

Comment: thank your for help, but I need to make it without table

Comment: @Belial check my edit. Also i have added jsFiddle, check the output there.

Comment: @Belial i have made the second div auto adjust. You can modify as needed. check this. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/